# Differential surface element and nabla operator

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

If we have the vector field $\vec{u}=\vec{A}\times \vec{v}$, where $\vec{A}=\text{const.}$ and we integrate over some closed curve, by using Stokes' theorem we get:
$$
\begin{align} 
\oint_{\partial S} \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{r} 
&= \iint_S \nabla\times(\vec{A}\times\vec{v}) \cdot d\vec{S} \\
&= \iint_S \bigl( \vec{A}(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}) 
- \vec{A} \cdot (\nabla \otimes\vec{v}) \bigr) \cdot d\vec{S} \\
&= \vec{A} \cdot \iint_S(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}) \cdot d\vec{S} 
- (\nabla \otimes\vec{v})\cdot d\vec{S}
\end{align}
$$
And at this point my textbook says that:
$$
(\nabla\otimes\vec{v}) \cdot d\vec{S} 
= \nabla(\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{S})
$$
I just can't understand why this equality holds when the differential vector $d\vec{S}$ depends on the coordinates and hence in not a constant generally. Can you give me a proof of why is that the  case?

Comment: Does [this calculation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/559444/23579) help?

Comment: I don't think it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$\vec u\otimes\vec w=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_1&w_2&w_3\end{bmatrix};\\
\vec u\cdot\vec w=\begin{bmatrix}u_1&u_2&u_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_1\\w_2\\w_3\end{bmatrix};\\
\nabla\phi=\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\phi\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
(\nabla\otimes\vec v)\cdot d\vec S&=\left(\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}dS_1\\dS_2\\dS_3\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}dS_1\\dS_2\\dS_3\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\\\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\vec v\cdot d\vec S\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\nabla(\vec v\cdot d\vec S).
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$(\nabla\otimes\vec v)\cdot d\vec S=\nabla(\vec v\cdot d\vec S).$$